# Google rejects OAuth 2 Javax.Mail API with bad credentials

Tags: java, oauth-2.0, gmail

`java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: 535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at 535 5.7.8  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials v7-20020a4a8607000000b0041bdf977c6dsm58061ooh.31 - gsmtp`

I am receiving this error when attempting to use javax.mail API to send emails over my GMail account. I attempted to check my settings to verify it allows less secure apps to use my GMail account but the Google website says

```
To help keep your account secure, from May 30, 2022, ​​Google no longer supports the use of third-party apps or devices which ask you to sign in to your Google Account using only your username and password.
```

Does anyone know where I can find a current guide on how to build hooks to send/receive mail messages with my GMail account that gets around these new requirements?

Answer (score 4):

1. **Access the page** with your Gmail/Google Account -> https://myaccount.google.com/security
2. In the Signing in to Google section, **enable the 2-Step Verification**
3. After enabling 2-Step Verification, return to **Signing in to Google** section
4. Click on **App passwords**
5. Select **app as Mail** and select **device as Other** - choose a name
6. **Done!** Copy the password and use it with the username account